# How To Insert The Form Data In Database Without Specifying It As "required" In Rule()

Tags: php, yii

I have some problems of receiving form data in Yii framework. Please spare a bit time and help me. I appreciate it a lot.

My problem is, I defined a table in database and in that table I have a column, which is NOT REQUIRED for user input (hence I didn't specify it as "required" in rules() function in model). But at the same time, I expect to received input if any.

What I found by now is that the input for the "un-required" column will not store in the table. This is not what I want. Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

(Hi all, I just figured it out. hopes it help other people who have the same problem. my workaround is to declare that "un-required" column 'safe" in model).

Thank you all anyway!

Comment: Sounds like you are making models with Gii generator?

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried ??

Answer (score 0):

There don't require a column that must have to specify '`required`' at rule for saving a model attribute into your database. The '`require`' rule is just applied for validator.
The problem which you got when saving model, it should come from other location, such as where  you begin to set value from form into the model attributes

Answer (score 0):

You should add that un-required parameter in safe rule, as i specified field_3 in following code
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

```
public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                    // fields which is required
                    array('field_1, field_2', 'required'),
                    /*You should add your parameter with safe rule here*/
                    array('field_3', 'safe')
            );
        }
```